# Django Try Except Not Working

Tags: python, django

I have this code,

```
    try:
        print "what"
        newClassName = CourseNameAndCodeAssociation.objects.get(departmentCode__iexact =         nameAndNumberStore[0])
        print newClassName  
    except:
        print "HAHA"
```

This always prints "HAHA", despite the fact that I've run the newClassName = ... code in console and it's worked.

Why is this happening?

**EDIT**

```
def newGetAllInformation(searchTerm):
nameAndNumberStore = modifySearchTerm(searchTerm)
urlStore = modifyUrl(nameAndNumberStore) # need to make the change here -- why not I go to the site, check for Course name - if that is not there switch, if it is  then scrape 
soup = getHtml(urlStore) 
storeOfBooks = []
storeOfBooks = scrape(soup,nameAndNumberStore)
print nameAndNumberStore[0]
try:
    newClassName = CourseNameAndCodeAssociation.objects.get(departmentCode__iexact = nameAndNumberStore[0])
    nameAndNumberStore = modifySearchTerm(newClassName.departmentName + " " + nameAndNumberStore[1])
    urlStore = modifyUrl(nameAndNumberStore)
    soup = getHtml(urlStore)
    storeOfBooks = scrape(soup,nameAndNumberStore)

except:
    print "HAHA"

return storeOfBooks
```

**EDIT**
After further investigation - that is, entering a valid code manually (which worked), I think that there's something up with taking the code from the array- despite the fact that both are the same data type (string).

so `newClassName = CourseNameAndCodeAssociation.objects.get(departmentCode__iexact = "econ")` works from file, but `newClassName = CourseNameAndCodeAssocition.objects.get(departmentCode__iexact = nameAndNumberStore[0])`,where `nameAndNumberStore[0]` holds **econ**

Comment: Have you tried, you know... letting the exception through?

Comment: I note that you don't have any imports in your code snippet. Maybe if you show us your whole console session, and all the code that affects your environment, we can help.

Comment: er, I'm importing BeautifulSoup, re, urllib2 and cookielib - there are a LOT of functions being called by this function as a whole- but I'll post the whole thing 

what do you mean by letting the exception through? I'm sort of new to programming - don't I need to catch it?

Answer (score 10):

Please modify the code to this, run it and tell us what exception you are getting:

```
try:
    print "what"
    newClassName = CourseNameAndCodeAssociation.objects.get(departmentCode__iexact =         nameAndNumberStore[0])
    print newClassName  
except Exception as e:
    print "HAHA"
    print e
```

Also, it would probably help to have a debugger installed on your box. I can recommend Eclipse in combination with PyDev, but that is a personal choice. There are lots of great options out there.

[Eclipse IDE - download the basic Java version of 120MB](http://eclipse.org/)

[then install this plugin on top of it - Pydev](http://pydev.org/)

Comment: OK- I have the exception - newClassName is nothing - and that's because departmentCode__iexact isn't finding what it's meant to be finding - I was passing in a code like 'econ', when the code stored was "ECON" - how can I do a case insensitive get?

Comment: You got that right. The Django spec says that iexact is that you should use. Can you make sure that you have not trailing white spaces? Try __icontains for a test. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-iexact

Comment: Hi praks5432, did you ever make sure that you have no trailing whitespaces? Did you try __icontains instead of __iexact?

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
except CourseNameAndCodeAssociation.DoesNotExist:
```

Each model you create gets its own `DoesNotExist` exception that extends core [`ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist) exception.

Also the best approach is to only use `try` … `except` around the precise line that you expect to fail. A more pythonic way to write what you have there would be:

```
department_code = name_and_number_store[0]
class_names = CourseNameAndCodeAssociation.objects.all()
try:
    new_class_name = class_names.get(departmentCode__iexact=department_code)
except CourseNameAndCodeAssociation.DoesNotExist:
    print "HAHA"
else:
    search_term = u'%s %s' % (new_class_name.departmentName,
                              name_and_number_store[1])
    name_and_number_store = modify_search_term(search_term)
    url_store = modify_url(name_and_number_store)
    soup = get_html(url_store)
    store_of_books = scrape(soup, name_and_number_store)
```

Please also note that the convention in Python is to use `lowercase_underscored_names` for variables, attributes and function names and `CamelCaseNames` for class names (instance names are either variables or attributes).